# Decorated $log fails in unit tests because of ngMock

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-ngmock, angular-providers, angular-decorator

In out project we have decorated $log service, that exposes a method .prefix().
We use it like `$log.prefix('Some Prefix text here')`.

This works fine in every module we use $log in, but not the unit tests:

> $log.prefix is not a function

It has to do that $log is changed by ngMock module. As we use $log.prefix in every of our modules, I don't want to rewrite every unit test of these modules.

**Question: Is there a way to decorate the $log method of ngMock?**